# Flex Row, Parent and Child Relationship

Tags: html, css

For the life of me I cannot get this flex row to work it always end up in a column, I have stripped this all the way down to basics and it still doesn't seem to work. I thought all flex properties were inherited from the parent, so I don't understand where I have gone wrong.

```css
  /* Header Video Full Screen */

  /* Header Video Full Screen Table/Word Box*/

  /* Product Recommendations Box*/

.productFlexParent{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.productFlexChild{
  width: 30%;
}

.productFlexImage{
max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <!-- Header Video/Photo of Product -->
  <video>
    <source>
  </video>

  <!-- Computer Title Header and Configure Box if applicable -->
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <!-- 3D Rotator/Glam Video-->
</div>
<div>
  <!--Why buy from Auspec-->
</div>
<div>
  <!-- Bottom of page recommended specs/with toggle?-->

  <!-- Rounded Toggle switch -->
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>

  <!--3 different models of build-->
  <div class="productFlexParent">
    <div class="productFlexChild">
      <img class="productFlexImage" src="https://umbrellacreative.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/hide-the-pain-harold-why-you-should-not-use-stock-photos-1024x683.jpg" alt="">
    </div> </div> <div class="productFlexParent">
    <div class="productFlexChild">
      <img class="productFlexImage" src="https://umbrellacreative.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/hide-the-pain-harold-why-you-should-not-use-stock-photos-1024x683.jpg" alt="">
    </div> </div> <div class="productFlexParent">
    <div class="productFlexChild">
      <img class="productFlexImage" src="https://umbrellacreative.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/hide-the-pain-harold-why-you-should-not-use-stock-photos-1024x683.jpg" alt="">
    </div> </div> 
  </div>
```

Comment: What exactly is your intent? – Perhaps you try `<div style="display: flex"><!-- Bottom ...?`  and see, if that's a path to your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put all your `<div class="productFlexChild">` in a single `<div class="productFlexParent">`.

If you put all your `<div class="productFlexChild">` in a different `<div class="productFlexParent">`, the `<div class="productFlexChild">` won't have any connection.

You can read the following site, if you want to read more about Flexbox or would like an example: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox_container.asp

Comment: Thank you, a simple oversight. I was trying to build 3 column divs that I could then add elements to. I was trying to be logical without following the rules